# Why is my json array not outputing input type radio for each line

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I don't know why the radio is only outputing the whole line choices and not each of them. I am trying to do a quiz/result code

```
HTML FILE

<html><br>
<head><br>
<meta charset="UTF-8"><br>
<title>Coffee Addict Quiz</title><br>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><br>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script><br>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container"><br>
<h1> How much of a coffee addict are you?</h1>

<div class="questionCon"></div><br>
<div class="questionCon"></div><br>
<div class="questionCon"></div><br>
<div class="questionCon"></div> <br>

</div><br>
<script src="js/questions.json"></script><br>
<script src="js/xml.js"></script>

</body><br>
</html>
```

JSON file

```
[{
  "question": "What does your morning look like?",
  "choices": ["Go for run", "Make coffee", "Cant talk running late!!"]
}, {
  "question": "How many cups of coffee you drink in a day?",
  "choices": ["None", "1-3", "4-7"]
}, {
  "question": "Which sounds the best right now?",
  "choices": ["Cappuccino", "Latte", "Espresso"]
}, {
  "question": "Do you drink coffee to pull all nighters?",
  "choices": ["No, I like my sleep", "Sometimes", "Yes"]
}]
```

JS FILE

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var questionCons = document.querySelectorAll(".questionCon");
    console.log(questionCons)

    function loadquestions() {
        $.getJSON("js/questions.json")
          .done(function(questions) {
            console.log(questions);
            for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
              questionCons[i].innerHTML += //plus and equal so it doesnt overright everyvalue.
                "<p>" + questions[i].question + "</p>" + '<input type="radio" >' + questions[i].choices;

            }
          })

        .fail(function() {
              alert("your browser is outdated");
```

Comment: please show us the HTML

Comment: There is a nice edit function allowing you to correctly format your code. Perhaps take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! Need to add `name` attribute in input tag

Example Snippet:

```js
var test = [{
  "question": "What does your morning look like?",
  "choices": ["Go for run", "Make coffee", "Cant talk running late!!"]
}, {
  "question": "How many cups of coffee you drink in a day?",
  "choices": ["None", "1-3", "4-7"]
}, {
  "question": "Which sounds the best right now?",
  "choices": ["Cappuccino", "Latte", "Espresso"]
}, {
  "question": "Do you drink coffee to pull all nighters?",
  "choices": ["No, I like my sleep", "Sometimes", "Yes"]
}]

var questionCons = document.querySelectorAll(".questionCon");

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  questionCons[i].innerHTML += "<p>" + test[i].question + "</p>";
  $.each(test[i].choices, function(index, value) {
    questionCons[i].innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name=quistion"' + i + '" >' + value;
  })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionCon"></div>
<div class="questionCon"></div>
<div class="questionCon"></div>
<div class="questionCon"></div>
```

Comment: But I want each to have a radio, example
o Go for a run
o Make coffe
o Cant talk running late

Comment: @panchita911 : updated the answer. Take a look. You need to add name attribute in input radio tag

Comment: @panchita911 : Did you take a look at updated answer

Comment: I did and it works, thank you!!!
 Now I just have to figure out how to get different results when the user clicks on the choices

Comment: @panchita911 : Good to hear that. Mark answer as correct it will help others identify the correct answer.

Comment: @panchita911 sorry I am not able to get what exactly is that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where you loop over the questions and the choices for each question, including setting the `name` and `value` attributes on the radio buttons (important if you plan to submit the form).

```js
var test = [{
  "question": "What does your morning look like?",
  "choices": ["Go for run", "Make coffee", "Cant talk running late!!"]
}, {
  "question": "How many cups of coffee you drink in a day?",
  "choices": ["None", "1-3", "4-7"]
}, {
  "question": "Which sounds the best right now?",
  "choices": ["Cappuccino", "Latte", "Espresso"]
}, {
  "question": "Do you drink coffee to pull all nighters?",
  "choices": ["No, I like my sleep", "Sometimes", "Yes"]
}]

var questions = document.getElementById('questions');

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  questions.innerHTML += "<p>" + test[i].question + "</p>";
  var questionId = 'question_' + i;
  for (var j = 0; j < test[i].choices.length; j++) {
    var choiceId = questionId + '_choice_' + j;
    questions.innerHTML += '<input id="' + choiceId + '" name="' + questionId + '" value="' + j + '" type="radio" ><label for="' + choiceId + '">' + test[i].choices[j] + '</label><br />';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't loop over the answers.  One (untested) extension looks like this:

```
.done(function(questions) {
  console.log(questions);
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    questionCons[i].innerHTML += 
      "<p>" + questions[i].question + "</p>";
    for (var j = 0; j < questions[i].choices.length; j++) {
      questionCons[i].innerHTML += 
        '<input type="radio" >' + questions[i].choices[j];
    }
  }
})
```

I would usually prefer to do it with `map` though:

```
.done(function(questions) {
  console.log(questions);
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    questionCons[i].innerHTML += 
      "<p>" + questions[i].question + "</p>" +
      questions[i].choices.map(function(choice) {
        return '<input type="radio" >' + choice;
      });
  }
})
```

(also untested)